# Relation between stakeholder and functional requirements

Tags: sysml, requirements-management

I'm currently struggling with some basic requirement management:

Given a set of stakeholder requirements I refine them by an equal set of use cases to identify underlying activities/functional requirements satisfied by a set of functions to fulfill the initial stakeholder requirements.
These use cases may lead to a redundancy in the identified activities which i guess is okay, but should not lead to redundant functional requirements but be covered by an unique requirement for all the redundant use case activities.

Is there a certain way how to structure/relate functional requirements and the belonging stakeholder requirements? How do I handle the 1:n relation between a functional requirement and the stakeholder requirements?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You say you refine the *stakeholder requirements* with *use cases* and identify *functional requirements* by analysing the use cases. So there would be a «refine» relationship between the use case and the stakeholder requirement. The functional requirements would have a «trace» relationship to the use case. So there is in indirect relationship between the functional requirement and the stakeholder requirement. If you want to visualize it in a matrix, your modeling tool should be able to show a matrix with implied relationships (mine is).